# using ant ivy in netbeans

Tags: netbeans, ant, build, ivy

Since I am new to Ant+Ivy this might sound very naive question but please bear with me. I recently installed Ivy [plugin](https://code.google.com/p/ivybeans/) to work with netbeans. But I don't know what to do next? Do I have to create ivy.xml file myself ? do I have to add its reference to nbbuild.xml somewhere? if yes where?

and finally how to write ivy.xml to fetch latest versions of the libraries I am using. e.g. I am using jgraph.jar, commons-codec-1.6.jar etc, Can somebody demonstrate how to write code in ivy.xml file to fetch the latest versions of these? These are available in the [maven central repository](http://search.maven.org/), Can I connect to that thru ivy.xml? If yes how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following answer to your other question gives a detailed example of a working ivy enabled project:

- [Use Ant in netbeans to dynamically fetch latest versions of external libraries during build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17079198/use-ant-in-netbeans-to-dynamically-fetch-latest-versions-of-external-libraries-d/17095611#17095611)

Yes, you'll have to create the [ivy.xml](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/ivyfile.html) file yourself, but Maven Central makes this really easy. Your examples are as follows:

- [jgraph](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cjgraph%7Cjgraph%7C5.13.0.0%7Cjar)
- [commons-codec-1.6](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccommons-codec%7Ccommons-codec%7C1.6%7Cjar)

Just copy-n-paste the ivy dependency declarations into your ivy.xml file:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency org="jgraph" name="jgraph" rev="5.13.0.0" />
  <dependency org="commons-codec" name="commons-codec" rev="1.6" />
</dependencies>
```

## Update

If you want to latest revision of a dependency then use the [dynamic revisions feature](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/ivyfile/dependency.html).

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency org="jgraph" name="jgraph" rev="latest.release" />
  <dependency org="commons-codec" name="commons-codec" rev="latest.release" />
</dependencies>
```

Be warned this can lead to build instability as 3rd party projects will change over time.

Comment: Another question, so now the rev is 5.13.0.0. Whenever there is a new version of jGraph, wlill my ivy.xml automatically know that and fetch it for me?

Comment: And one last question is about nbbuild.xml : now that I have ivy.xml file, How to include it in nbbuild.xml or how to tell nbbuild.xml to refer to this file ?

Comment: @tejas I have updated the answer. I don't use netbeans so I don't know what the nbbuild.xml file is. I suspect it's a generated build file, in which case you'll have to integrate the changes. Perhaps look at the netbeans IDE I suggested in the other question.

Comment: Thanks for your support so far. I'll find out on how to integrate it to nbbuild.xml.